# Hiding and faking my location?

Tags: vpn, ip, geolocation

I read this:

[Reveal the True IP of a User](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13109/reveal-the-true-ip-of-a-user)

I am using `Hola Unblocker` to hide my IP address. This appears to work when I go to netflix as the site treats me as a US resident (which I am not).
This however does not work when I go to:
https://www.crashplanpro.com/business/signup.html

They seem to be able to figure I'm not from the US.
I am wondering how they accomplish this? Is there any way to circumvent this method and protect my privacy? Does it matter what type of VPN I'm using?

Answer (score 3):

Most companies have lists of VPN IP's and will block them to prevent users from outside the country to use their services. So they probably can't "see" you are using a VPN, but the recognize the IP and block that.

Comment: I am not so sure. It says on Hola that: "Typical VPNs need to maintain servers in various countries and to route your traffic through those servers in order to change your IP. This is very expensive. Hola is a network of peers that help each other to access censored content, thereby dramatically reducing the cost of the service. Where typical VPNs charge about $10 per month for the service, to cover their servers costs and make a profit, Hola can provide you this service as either ad-based, or a ad-free, uninterrupted service for a much much lower cost... So no server IP to block

Comment: I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure about this one either. They do seem to have a lot of issues with browser plugins. Have a look at their FAQ.

Comment: Perhaps it asked your browser to know your location? Browser location is usually defined by the WiFi network you using... so even when connected to VPN it would still tell your real location.(by the way - in order for it to use the browser's location you need to approve it)

Answer (score 0):

It'slikely this company uses fraud screening (MaxMind, Varilogix or others) to check for signups using Proxy/VPN.

You could either drum up a server from a server provider (DigitalOcean, Linode) that offers presance in the US and install a quick VPN

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-openvpn-access-server-on-ubuntu-12-04

https://library.linode.com/networking/openvpn

Then use this vpn to signup.

Depending on the service however there may be a reason they aren't providing a service outsite these countries. So you could also try finding a service which is available in your area (Stupid answer I know but probably the most sensible) (Backblaze, Mozy, Carbonite)